# Voice Over alternative for Core Plot graph?

Tags: ios, ios5, accessibility, core-plot, voiceover

I have a graph view in my application to display statistical information.

Has anybody managed to create any real implementation for voice over with core plot?

How could I make this an alternative "view" for visually impaired users?

For example how could I make it speak the x-y values one by one?
So when the view loads the first value pair is spoken, then the user can swipe left, right to go to the next which is spoken and so on.

Update by request

I have two different types of graph views.
One is for displaying medication compliance. This graph displays the percentage of missed, postponed and 'on time' intakes of medication averaged for every week.
Another graph shows measured information, for example blood pressure. This is not with a fixed interval. So the x-axis is displaying the dates when this measurement was done.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the information the graph will be displaying? The best bet is to describe the information, not the graph itself — but it depends whether your non-VoiceOver users will be using the graph for an overview or whether they'll care about the detail. If an overview, reading the actual values is no use, you want to describe trends or meaningful info.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same issue in our app and finished by presenting to VoiceOver users a totally different user interface.

Instead of displaying a graph I'm displaying a list of values since our graphs are either a pie chart or a bar graph with determined values. A UITableView is much more easier to make accessible.

You can check the VoiceOver status with `UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()` and decide to display either the graph or a table view.
Our VO users gave us excellent feedback and thanked us a lot for this

Answer (score 1):

Look how it's done in Apple's Stocks app that is part of iOS - for accessibility, the graph view has children, each being a single x-y value. So you would implement the UIAccessibilityContainer protocol in the plot view to return a bunch of UIAccessibilityElement instances, each representing a single data point and returning an accessibilityValue of e.g. "week 1, 21% missed, 14% postponed, 65% on time", then next UIAccessibilityElement "week 2, ..." and so on. Or perpahs try accessibilityLabel "week 1" and accessibilityValue "21% missed, 14% postponed, 65% on time". The accessibilityTraits of these could be UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText.

Also don't forget to set the correct accessibilityFrame on the UIAccessibilityElement instances - that will allow the VoiceOver users to "touch-explore" (move the finger around) the graph for random access on the x-axis (where applicable). Again try the Stocks app to see how this works.